# Trying to simulate the card game War in Matlab. When playing two cards against each other, number cards work fine, but face cards do not

Tags: matlab

As the title states, I am having trouble making things work in my program of the card game War when it comes to face cards. What I have currently is:

```
card_nums = ('23456789TJQKA')';
card_suits = ('HDSC')';
unshuffled_deck = [repmat(card_nums,4,1),repmat(card_suits,13,1)];
disp(unshuffled_deck)
fprintf('\n')

shuffled_deck = unshuffled_deck(randperm(size(unshuffled_deck,1)),:);
disp(shuffled_deck)
fprintf('\n')

player1_hand = shuffled_deck(1:26, 1:2);
disp(player1_hand)
fprintf('\n')

player2_hand = shuffled_deck(27:52, 1:2);
disp(player2_hand)
fprintf('\n')

T = 10;
J = 11;
Q = 12;
K = 13;
A = 14;

if shuffled_deck(1, 1) > shuffled_deck(27, 1)
fprintf('Player 1 wins \n')
elseif shuffled_deck(1, 1) < shuffled_deck(27, 1)
fprintf('Player 2 wins \n')
else
fprintf('It is a tie.')
end
```

Everything works, it deals the cards, creates and shuffles the deck just fine, and displays each card perfectly. When it comes to actually comparing cards though, it will work for the most part. Two number cards against each other such as an 8 and a 6? It will work flawlessly. However, when a face card is introduced into the mix it doesn't work very well. The biggest culprit seems to be the Ace, no matter what I do if an Ace and let's say a 10 are pitted against eachother, the program will side with the 10. I'm not very sure how to fix this, but so much as just pointing me in the right direction would be extremely helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're not comparing the variable A (or whatever face card) against the number. You're comparing the *character* A against the number, and when you do that, Matlab automatically converts the character to its ASCII value. If you run `uint8('A')` and `uint8('T')`, you'll see that A has the value 65 and T has the value 84. So 'T' > 'A', even though 10 is less than ace.

What you should be doing is representing the face cards by the card's numerical value, not messing with characters. So you would shuffle the numbers 2 to 14, and then convert 11-14 to Jack-Ace if you want to print the card names. Also, it doesn't seem like the suit is even taken into account, so you could just discard that part entirely. Really the whole deck can just be represented by `A = repmat(2:14, [1, 4])`, and you can shuffle it by doing `B = A(randperm(length(A)))`.

Comment: Alright so I tried to recreate the deck with the code you posted and it works, but it doesn't shuffle. I used the same randperm function as I was using before and it won't shuffle the deck. Any thoughts?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I forgot you were using `randperm`. You can represent the deck as `A = repmat(2:14, [1, 4])` and shuffle it using `B = A(randperm(length(A)))`.

Comment: That worked, thank you! I will try to rewrite the code around this deck instead as it seems like it would be much less of a hassle than dealing with suits and face cards, my professor didn't specify either way so I'm sure it will be fine.